# Where do I find missing query string paramters for Google Analytics in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome, universal-analytics

I can't find standard **Google Analytics paramters** in the **query string** of the **collect image** that sends the param-value-pairs to my Google Analytics account.

In the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools I search for analytics and take look at the collect image query string, like so:

[image]

Why are there no param-value-pairs listed for information that is captured by default, like [**dh** for hostname](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dh) or [**dr** for the referrer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr)?

Can I find them somewhere else?

Comment: Well, you could always try using the Tag Assistant chrome plugin to debug your GA implementation.

Comment: Your references indicate that those parameters are both optional so perhaps they were not set, or were set as undefined.

Comment: I thought the mentioned parameters are mandatory as in automatically extracted from the header information (like the hostname).
@nyuen Where does my reference that those parameters were optional? I've just taken the information from a random site (I think lunametrics), which implements Google Analytics. Is there a reference web page/other source that documents, how to extract exactly what is sent via Google Analytics when a Tag fires?

Comment: @SomewhereDave, in the links you provided to the Google support pages, it says "Optional" right underneath the header.

Comment: From what I understand "optional" in that case means, you may specify those paramters, but if you don't they are automatically extracted from the header. In Google Analytics every pageview also has an attributed hostname (otherwise its spam), which usually is your URL. I would still like to see where and when this parameter is set, if its not deliberatly set in the GA Javascript snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As @nyuen pointed out the hostname is an optional query-string-parameter. What I failed to realize before is that Google Analytics automatically extracts the hostname from the full page url stored under the dl parameter, if the dr parameter isn't provided separartly.

In general, it seems GA paramters which are not set are notlisted in the query string. As for referrer, the dr parameter could not be found, because the URL was called from the browsers's address bar.